# Excel to PPT. VBA, code doesn't run first time but runs second. Error 462: remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, powerpoint

thank you for taking the time to read this message.

I am automating the conversion of an Excel file to PPT (early binding). The first time that the code is executed in prompts an error -462: the remote...- but the consecutive times it runs without an issue.

Could you please help me in figuring out why this happens?
Thank you!

```
'Forces explicit variable declaration
Option Explicit

'sheet_name returns the name of the spreadsheet (as string) needed
    '...to loop acording to the number of selected equities
    'Arguments: n_sheets = number of the loop for the selected equities
    '...n_slide = the type of slide (1 = Fact sheet, 2 = metrics summary
    'Process: concatenates and convers to string the int
    '...representative values
        
Function sheet_name(n_slide, n_sheets)

    Dim name As String
    
    name = "P" & CStr(n_slide) & "_C" & CStr(n_sheets)
    
    sheet_name = name

End Function


'slide_val returns the right slide number (as int) to print in the factsheet
    '...and the metrics summary
    'Arguments: n_slide = the type of slide (1 = Fact sheet, 2 = metrics summary
    '...n_equities = the number of the loop for the selected equities
    'Process: sets the factsheet slide  by duplicatating the equity number and substracting 1
    '... and sets the metric summary slide by duplicating the equity number so that
    '...(i.e. for equity 1, slide 1 = factsheet, slide 2 = metric summary;
    '...( for equity 2, slide 3 = factsheet, slide 4 = metric summary and so on)

Function slide_val(n_slide, n_equities)

    Dim first_slide As Integer
    Dim second_slide As Integer
    Dim return_val As Integer
    
    first_slide = n_equities * 2 - 1
    second_slide = n_equities * 2
    
    If n_slide = 1 Then
        return_val = first_slide
    ElseIf n_slide = 2 Then
        return_val = second_slide
    End If
    
    slide_val = return_val

End Function

Public Function PauseEvent(ByVal Delay As Double)
  Dim dblEndTime As Double
  dblEndTime = Timer + Delay
  Do While Timer < dblEndTime
    DoEvents
  Loop
End Function

Sub Generate_PPT()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Global Variables
    Dim pp_app As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pp_pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pp_slide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim pp_textB As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim Crop_left As Integer
    Dim Crop_others As Integer
    Dim Print_Area As String, Nombre As String, NumberC As Integer
    Dim wait_t As Double
    
    
    'Define and initiate PPT
    Set pp_app = New PowerPoint.Application
    pp_app.Visible = msoTrue
    pp_app.Activate
    
    'Define Presentation
    Set pp_pres = pp_app.Presentations.Add
    
    'Define variables
    Print_Area = "Print_Area"
    Crop_left = 2
    Crop_others = 5
    wait_t = 0.5
    Nombre = Worksheets("Cuadro_Mando").Range("B4").Value
    NumberC = Worksheets("Cuadro_Mando").Range("C14").Value
    
    'Set slides dimentions
    With pp_pres.PageSetup
        .SlideWidth = 800
        .SlideHeight = 600
    End With
    
    
    'Loop through the Excel sheets acording to the NumberC value and
        'and set create the respective slides
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To NumberC
    
   ' footer = True
    'First Slide--
    
        'Clear Clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        '1) Create and select slide, 2) copy worksheet object, 3) paste it in the PPT slide
            '...4)delay action 1 second to allow Excel to process the copy action
        Set pp_slide = pp_pres.Slides.Add(slide_val(1, i), ppLayoutBlank)   '1)
        pp_slide.Select
        Worksheets(sheet_name(1, i)).Range(Print_Area).Copy                 '2)
        PauseEvent (wait_t)                                                    '3)
        pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile                '4)
        
        'Set size and crop blue lines around the image
            'lines are copied as default due to the copy method (best alternative)
        With pp_slide.Shapes(1)
            .Width = 725
            .PictureFormat.CropBottom = Crop_others
            .PictureFormat.CropLeft = Crop_left
            .PictureFormat.CropRight = Crop_others
        End With
        
        'Align Sheet image in the PPT slide
        pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue
        pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
        pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 10
        
        'Footer
        'BBG data source
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Worksheets("Idiomas").Range("Data_source").Copy
        PauseEvent (wait_t)
        pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        With pp_slide.Shapes(2)
            .Left = -10
            .Top = 550
        End With
        
        'SPB image
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Worksheets("Idiomas").Shapes("SPB_footer").Copy
        PauseEvent (wait_t)
        pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        With pp_slide.Shapes(3)
            .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 15
            .PictureFormat.CropTop = 15
            .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 18
            .PictureFormat.CropRight = 18
            .Left = 700
            .Top = 550
        End With


    'Second Slide--
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set pp_slide = pp_pres.Slides.Add(slide_val(2, i), ppLayoutBlank)
        pp_slide.Select
        Worksheets(sheet_name(2, i)).Range(Print_Area).Copy
        PauseEvent (wait_t)
        pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        With pp_slide.Shapes(1)
            .Width = 725
            .PictureFormat.CropBottom = Crop_others
            .PictureFormat.CropLeft = Crop_left
            .PictureFormat.CropRight = Crop_others
            .PictureFormat.CropTop = Crop_others
        End With
        pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue
        pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
        pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 15

        'Footer
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Worksheets("Idiomas").Range("Data_source").Copy
        PauseEvent (wait_t)
        pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        With pp_slide.Shapes(2)
            .Left = -10
            .Top = 550
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Worksheets("Idiomas").Shapes("SPB_footer").Copy
        PauseEvent (wait_t)
        pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        With pp_slide.Shapes(3)
            .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 15
            .PictureFormat.CropTop = 15
            .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 18
            .PictureFormat.CropRight = 18
            .Left = 700
            .Top = 550
        End With
    Next i
    
    'Disclaimer Slide--
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set pp_slide = pp_pres.Slides.Add(NumberC * 2 + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    pp_slide.Select
    Worksheets("Disclaimer").Range(Print_Area).Copy
    PauseEvent (wait_t)
    pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    With pp_slide.Shapes(1)
        .Width = 750
        .PictureFormat.CropBottom = Crop_others
        .PictureFormat.CropLeft = Crop_left
        .PictureFormat.CropRight = Crop_others
        .PictureFormat.CropTop = Crop_others
    End With
    pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue
    pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
    pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 100

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("Idiomas").Shapes("SPB_footer").Copy
    PauseEvent (wait_t)
    pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    With pp_slide.Shapes(2)
        .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 15
        .PictureFormat.CropTop = 15
        .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 18
        .PictureFormat.CropRight = 18
        .Left = 700
        .Top = 550
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line causes the error? When you try and create the Application object, or when you try to use it?

Comment: Apologies, the line is here
pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile